# Convert OUTER APPLY to LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

We have query which is slow in production(for some internal reason),

```
SELECT T2.Date
FROM Table1 T1
OUTER APPLY 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 T2.[DATE] 
    FROM Table2 T2 
    WHERE T1.Col1 = T2.Col1 
    AND T1.Col2 = T2.Col2 
    ORDER BY T2.[Date] DESC
) T2
```

But when I convert to LEFT JOIN it become fast,

```
SELECT Max(T2.[Date])
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2
   ON T1.Col1 = T2.Col1 
   AND T1.Col2 = T2.Col2
GROUP BY T1.Col1, T1.Col2
```

Can we say that both queries are equal? If not then how to convert it properly.

Comment: In addition, the logic suggested seems to rely on some assumptions. Using an aggregate should reduce the number of rows returned assuming the logic is analogous. Is it just luck based on the available data that you seem to think these are the same? Did  you try this and compare the results?

Comment: In your first query, the resultset will contain one row for every row in T1. In your second query, your aggregate will reduce the resultset if there are duplicated values of Col1 and Col2 in T1. So - logically they are not the same without assumptions (or DDL that demonstrates that this cannot occur).

Comment: They aren't fully equal. In case you have duplicates in Table1, the first query will return more records

Comment: And lastly - this query seems vastly more complicated than needed. So the better path is to define your goal rather than ask others to review your current code without understanding your schema and your purpose.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin thanks. In my case I am sure that T1.Col1, T1.Col2 are unique.

Comment: NB: This has a code smell; i.e. grouping by `T1.Col1` & `T1.Col2` (/ returning one date value per Table1 row) without returning those columns. i.e. It may be OK depending on what you plan to do with those dates, but seems odd to return a list of dates without returning something to give those rows any context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queries are not exactly the same.  It is important to understand the differences.

If `t1.col1`/`t1.col2` are duplicated, then the first query returns a separate row for each duplication.  The second combines them into a single row.

If either `t1.col1` or `t1.col2` are `NULL`, then the first query will return `NULL` for the maximum date.  The second will return a row and the appropriate maximum.

That said, the two queries should have similar performance, particularly if you have an index on `table2(col1, col2, date)`.  I should note that under some circumstances the `apply` method is faster than `join`s, so relative performance depends on circumstances.

Comment: thanks. In my case I am sure that T1.Col1, T1.Col2 are unique and not nullable :)